# How do I amend a suggested edit to a tag wiki?

Tags: support, feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I recently suggested [this edit](//stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14250356) to the [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) wiki. The problem is, I realized that I made a typo in my typo correction. Normally this isn't a problem because I can merely edit the post again and fix that. However, if I visit the [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) tag info, it just shows the "edit pending" message with a link to "Approve Tag Wiki Edits" privilege in the Help Center.

So how can I amend my suggested edit to fix it? (Alternatively, if a ♦ moderator or 20K user would review "Edit" and fix it there, it would be fine too. [UPDATE: This is what happened. Meta-effect is fun!])

Answer (score 2):

I think this issue is fixed now. While a suggested tag wiki edit is yet to be approved or rejected, you can click "Edit tag info" and amend your suggested edit.

However, if you have 5 pending edits, then you cannot amend your suggested edit that only improves either the wiki body or the excerpt. I think the reason is that when you edit a tag info, both excerpt and body are editable but they count as separate edits on the queue. As you can have at most 5 pending suggested edits and any amendment could potentially add one more suggested edit, the system blocks you if you already have 5 pending edits.